# Laravel | Class not Found

Tags: laravel

I would like ot integer an externe class with two functions into my laravel project.  This externe class serves for e-payment.

I created a new folder in \App named **xxx** then my php file named **xxx.php**.

My path is 
`\App\xxx\xxx.php`

When i would like to call this class in **XController** using this code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\xxx\xxx;
class XController extends Controller
{
   public function Send(Request $request){
   $function = new xxx;
   };
}
```

**A got an Error : Class 'App\xxx\xxx' not found**

my xxx.php code is like that :

```
<?php
 namespace App;
class xxx
{
 public function function($data)
 {
    return ;
 }
}
```

My route :

```
Route::get('/send', 'XController@Send');
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the namespace in your class file `Xxx.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Xxx;

class Xxx
{
    public function function($data)
    {
        return ;
    }
}
```

and run this command in your console

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Laravel uses PSR-4 autoloading so the class, folder and namespace must be capitalised.

Comment: Thought it was an evidence. I updated the answer so it reflects that

Comment: I got a second problem with code, if you have time, can you take a look to it ? Thank you ! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578216/laravel-cannot-send-data-using-url

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses PSR-4 autoloading, so you should ensure that your classes and folders are capitalised. You can read up more on PSR-4 here - https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

In your case the folder should be `Xxx` instead of `xxx` and your file should be called `Xxx` instead of `xxx`.

At the same time you also need to update the namespace on the `Xxx.php` file:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Xxx;

class Xxx
{
 public function function($data)
 {
    return ;
 }
}
```

Then within your controller you can update your use statement and the method.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Xxx\Xxx;

class XController extends Controller
{
   public function Send(Request $request){
       $function = new Xxx;
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The issue he's having is not related to PSR-4, event if the namespace/classes are not capitalized, they would still work. the issue was he had the wrong namespace declared in his class.

Answer (score 1):

in **`xxx.php`** file namespace should be like this :

```
 namespace App\folderName;     // App\xxx;
```

and then run

```
   php artisan config:cache;
```